# SQL query is added to DB but thinks it is wrong crashing the python program

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, kivy

(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '')' at line 1")

I do not understand why "')" chucks an error

I have tried substituting the values of the query in multiple different ways
and they all route back to that.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

query in question:

sql = "INSERT INTO Teams VALUES (%s, %s)"

cursor.execute(sql, (self.varTeamID, self.varTeamName))

alternate attempts chucking same error:

sql = "INSERT INTO Teams VALUES (" + self.varTeamID + ", '" + self.varTeamName + "')"

Please note that the query works and is added to the database however python thinks it is wrong crashing the program

Comment: This code is unsafe from SQL injection. Please use Prepared Statements instead. With that, your errors *may* also go away

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I don't mind if it can be hacked with SQL injection as it's not going to be used for anything. I just want it not to crash python when executing.

Comment: Still, it's never a bad time to learn about our friend bobby tables: http://bobby-tables.com Check the python section to see how to make it properly.

Comment: @Saelyth I know, I really should absolutely learn it sometime and thanks for the example but I really don't have time right now as I am in a rush and I just need to get it working.

Comment: Just as a test, try calling `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Teams (TeamID, TeamName) VALUES (%s, %s)", (90, 'test'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found it, this statement was working fine, the error was actually in the next SQL statement just after this one.

Answer (score 0):

These may be the reasons why your SQL query is not working:

1. If the `Teams` table has more than two columns in its schema, then you should rephrase your statement as follows: 
   `INSERT INTO Teams (col1_name, col2_name) VALUES ("%s", "%s");`
   where `col1_name` and `col2_name` are the actual names of the columns, between single or double quotation marks if they contains spaces.
2. You should enclose the values between single or double quotation marks: 
   `INSERT INTO Teams VALUES ("%s", "%s");`
3. You may need to end the query with a semicolon.

Comment: Thanks for the input however this doesn't seem to work either

Comment: Can you provide the table schema and some sample data you want to put in the table?

Comment: Yea, sure it's TeamID(int, 5) and TeamName(VarChar, 100), the data I entered to test with was (90, 'test'). If the data is committed it is added to the database. The problem is that sql/python thinks that the query is incorrect when it isn't (or maybe it is I don't know) and once the query is sent and does it's thing the program crashes.

Comment: I really can't get what's wrong with your query. Something like INSERT INTO Teams VALUES(90, test); should raise an exception like "test table not found", not a syntax error. The only reason I can think of is that you pass a null string as second value, so that when the second '%s' is replaced you get INSERT INTO Teams VALUES(90, ); which is a syntax error.

Comment: Yea maybe, but if that was the case the query wouldn't work at all. Because it still submits the correct values to the database.

Comment: Each INSERT statement is evaluated by itself. So if you have a set of N data to insert into the table and the k-th record has a null string in it, all records from 1 to k-1 will be inserted correctly into the table, but all records from k to N will not be inserted, because the k-th record will raise a syntactic error. I guess that the `self` in your question refers to some container object who stores all the records about the team, then the `cursor.execute()` execute an INSERT statement for each element in the container.

Comment: @A.Semat Your point 1 would result in `ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`. In Python, using MySQLdb, you should not quote the %s characters. Also, you don't need to use semicolons.

Comment: @Wodin You are right. About point (2), I mistook an SQL placeholder for plain string substitution. I am accustomed to sqlite3 ? placeholder, but this is a question about mysql. My bad.